# Cookie with JS, IE trouble

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies

I'm having a problem with making a cookie in IE (8) with javascript. Of course it works in any other browser than IE. The cookie will not be created in IE.

it looks something like this:

```
document.cookie = 'my_name=my_value;expires=0;path=/my_project/;domain=localhost';
```

I want the expires to be 0, i want it removed when the user closes the browser.

Anyone that can tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: what trouble are you having? is there an exception? does the cookie just not get created?

Comment: Yea sorry i'm a retard some times. Id's not created...

Comment: @gubbfett: Chances are that, the domain name value doesn't match with the one where the page is opened. Try removing the `domain` field entirely.